# Make image overlay responsive

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I've created a simple image overlay by placing an image with the with `position:absolute` over another image.

As I resize the window the image overlay loses its initial position, causing the two images to seperate. I need them to stick to the same position until the screen reaches mobile width.

Below is the code & here is a **[codepen](https://codepen.io/jordan_miguel/pen/qPBpMo?editors=1100)**.

HTML -

```
<div class="projects">
  <div id="images" class="stella">
    <div class="desktop-image">
      <img src="https:http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article10811001.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Arsenal-player-Alexandre-Lacazette-takes.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-image-stella">
      <img src="https:http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article10811001.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Arsenal-player-Alexandre-Lacazette-takes.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="images" class="scf">
    <div class="desktop-image">
      <img src="https:http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article10811001.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Arsenal-player-Alexandre-Lacazette-takes.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="images" class="misma">
    <div class="desktop-image">
      <img src="http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article10811001.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Arsenal-player-Alexandre-Lacazette-takes.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-image-misma">
      <img src="https:http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article10811001.ece/ALTERNATES/s1200/Arsenal-player-Alexandre-Lacazette-takes.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.projects {
  width: 100;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#images {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 230px;
}

#images img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #0f0f10;
}

.mobile-image-stella {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 112%;
  left: 22%;
}

.mobile-image-misma {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 332%;
  left: 22%;
}
```

And here is a media query that I tried in order to fix the problem

```
@media (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1428px) {
  .mobile-image-stella {
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 112%;
    left: 22%;
  }

  .mobile-image-misma {
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 332%;
    left: 22%;
  }
}
```

Comment: where you want to position the image??

Comment: In the same position regardless of screen width

Comment: on top of big image or where?

Comment: yes on top of the big image

Comment: https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/gGOvRp?editors=1100 is this what you need

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: check the link again

Comment: If you look at the codepen each small image is sort of hanging off the bigger image, purely for aesthetic reasons. For example the first picture should stay at the position of `top:112%` & `left:22%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, I re-coded the larger image to be the `background-image` of `desktop-image`, so that I can give the `position:relative` to it properly. It is just a matter of making the smaller image the child of the larger image, and positioning using `position:absolute` to its proper placement.

This should make the smaller image's position "static", even if resizing the browser. If I misunderstood something, just comment it and I will edit accordingly

```css
.desktop-image {
  background-image: url('https://images.cdn.fourfourtwo.com/sites/fourfourtwo.com/files/styles/image_landscape/public/lacazette-cropped_1du1hebls4tv11c8ef7kdpyok1.jpg?itok=Lh3EAtTj&c=87b6d99828d88c1b8ffe17a08d24fc7d');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid #0f0f10;
  position: relative;
}

.desktop-image>img {
  width: 30%;
  border: 5px solid #0f0f10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <div class="desktop-image">
    <img class="mobile-image-stella" src="https://images.cdn.fourfourtwo.com/sites/fourfourtwo.com/files/styles/image_landscape/public/lacazette-cropped_1du1hebls4tv11c8ef7kdpyok1.jpg?itok=Lh3EAtTj&c=87b6d99828d88c1b8ffe17a08d24fc7d">
  </div>
</div>
```